# Join 3 tables with a limit

Tags: mysql, join

I have created this query to select entries from a table timeline and enrich those with data from my users table. Now I would like to select just (1) entry media.filename from the media table where media.album = '0', the result of my query is returning now what I want but it returns all entries from the media table and I need only one. Where could I put my condition or limit 1 ?

```
SELECT dat, sourceinfo, users.firstname, users.lastname, users.token, users.prof,
media.filename from timeline
JOIN users ON users.user_id = timeline.userid2 JOIN media ON users.user_id = 
timeline.userid2 
WHERE (timeline.user_id = '25') and (dat BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 
DAY) AND NOW())
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `LIMIT` clause in a subquery.

```
SELECT dat, sourceinfo, users.firstname, users.lastname, users.token, users.prof,
        media.filename
FROM timeline
JOIN users ON users.user_id = timeline.userid2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT filename
            FROM media
            WHERE album = 0
            LIMIT 1) AS media
```

Or you can put the subquery in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT dat, sourceinfo, users.firstname, users.lastname, users.token, users.prof,
       (SELECT filename
        FROM media
        WHERE album = 0
        LIMIT 1) AS filename
FROM timeline
JOIN users ON users.user_id = timeline.userid2
```